# use package typewriter with wrapfigure

Tags: wrapfigure, typewriter

[image]I would like to have two pictures side by side on the right side of the page with text floating around. This works fine until I try to use the package `typewriter`. Then the two pictures are one upon another and there is a strange line below the pictures. Is there a way to prevent that even with the package `typewriter`?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{graphicx}  
    \usepackage{wrapfig} 
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{lipsum} 
    \providecommand\ttgreyone{0.6}
    \providecommand\ttgreytwo{0.3}
    \providecommand\ttrotatebold{12}
    \providecommand\ttdownbold{20000}
    \providecommand\ttrightbold{35000}
    \providecommand\ttdownshifttwo{20000}
    \providecommand\ttrotatenormal{8}
    \providecommand\ttrightnormal{20000}
    \providecommand\ttdownnormal{20000}    
    \usepackage{typewriter}   
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}   

    \begin{document}
        \section*{text}
        \subsection*{text}
    \lipsum[1]
        \begin{wrapfigure}   {r} {0.5\textwidth} 
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{.25\textwidth}  
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} 
            \end{subfigure}  \hspace{0.1cm}%
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{.25\textwidth}  
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} 
            \end{subfigure}  \hspace{0.1cm}
        \end{wrapfigure}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{graphicx}  
    \usepackage{wrapfig} 
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{lipsum} 
    \providecommand\ttgreyone{0.6}
    \providecommand\ttgreytwo{0.3}
    \providecommand\ttrotatebold{12}
    \providecommand\ttdownbold{20000}
    \providecommand\ttrightbold{35000}
    \providecommand\ttdownshifttwo{20000}
    \providecommand\ttrotatenormal{8}
    \providecommand\ttrightnormal{20000}
    \providecommand\ttdownnormal{20000}    
    \usepackage{typewriter}   


    \begin{document}
        \section*{text}
        \subsection*{text}

        \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth} 
                \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill
                \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image}
\let\hrule\oldhrule
        \end{wrapfigure}
    \mbox{}\lipsum*[1]

    \end{document}
```

Comment: That was simple.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have seen the package before. (actually the hardest part was working round lipsum weirdness that stops wrapfig)

Comment: Spectacular resolution of the problem. Good memories when I used my own typewriter.